# New Unity Vr Project Unable to Install XR Interaction Toolkit

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I installed Unity 2022.1.11f1 in a folder on my D drive since my C drive is nearly full (I think this may be part of the problem). I made a new project with the VR Core template. When I try to install XR Interaction toolkit I get these error messages:

```
    [Package Manager Window] Cannot perform upm operation: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'D:\Stuff-thats-on-my-desktop\Random Coding Stuff\Unity\Games\Vr Newest\Library\PackageCache\.tmp-13992-4IcEoKfKjCQJ' [NotFound].
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()

    [Package Manager Window] Error adding package: com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

I also get similar error messages when I open the project. I've found nothing on the internet related to this and have no clue how to solve it so I really appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Unity like pretty much every other package manager loves to store packages and caches on **C:** either in **Program Files** or **C:\Users\...\AppData**.  Use the tool _WinDirStat_ to find out what's taking up the most space on **C:**.  Once found you can move it to another drive then create a _directory junction_ from the original folder to where you moved it (say D:). **C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming** is great to  move.  Generally not a good idea to use directory junctions for anything under Program Files.   https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link

Comment: ...https://superuser.com/questions/1250288/can-i-move-my-appdata-folder-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. Completely uninstalled unity and reinstalled it entirely on my D drive under /Unity with the subfolders Projects, Editors, and Downloads for each respective setting in Unity Hub, everything worked perfectly after that.